# Bing Maps Tile Source Uri constructor set custom header

Tags: maps, bing-maps, bing

i need your help. I`m using bing maps tile source.

```
const tileSource = new Microsoft.Maps.TileSource({
  uriConstructor: 'someapi',
  enableCors: true,
  minZoom,
  maxZoom
});
```

I'm using REST api and it needs header for security. i can`t understand how can i set a header in uri constructor if it only needs string. I know that i can use callback, but it is also return only string. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Tile layers in Bing Maps do not expose a way to set the header on tile requests.